# SQL select query, is this a correct solution?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have been practicing SQL online and I am having doubt in one exercise. In the following database:

**product** (prod id, product name, product price, product manufacturer)

**customer** (cust id, customer name, customer address)

**rating** (prod id, cust id, rating date, rating stars)

**sale** (sale id, prod id, cust id, sale quantity, sale cost)

"For all cases in which the same customer rated the same product
more than once, and in some point in time gave it a lower rating
than before, return the customer name, the name of the product,
and the lowest star rating that was given."

I am not entirely sure about the answer, this is what I got:

```
SELECT customer_name,
       product_name,
       min(rating_stars)
FROM customer,
     product,
     rating
WHERE rating_stars < SOME
    (SELECT rating_stars
     FROM customer,
          product,
          rating)
GROUP BY customer,
         product,
         rating
```

Could any of you have a check in the code and see if it is correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct. Carthesian join on 3 tables, no check, if the same customer rated the same pruouct at least twice, lower rating should be later than the higher rating.

Comment: could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Which part of the comment is unclear?

Comment: In order to check if the customer rated the same product more than once, would it be possible to use the rename operation in the select statement, and then check if customer_name equals customer_A (for example) in the where statement, and do the same for the product?

Comment: No. You either have to use group by and count, or a self join, or an exists subquery.